# porting Socket programming from Ubuntu to Windows

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, firewall

I have the following connection in Ubuntu

**Linux PC -> Switch (PoE) -> DUT**

with the following ip configurations:

**Ethernet adaptor Statically assigned
BASE IP (ipv4): 10.0.0.1
subnet        : 255.255.255.0
gateway       : 10.0.0.0
eth0 network address : 10.0.0.3**

This setup enables me to send and receive UDP packets.Works perfectly fine in Ubuntu.

Now in Windows, I have made relevant changes to the python code of the codebase, but the code gets stuck waiting for UDP packets from the Hardware. I have statically assigned the same values as in Ubuntu. I am very new to networking..

**(1) I have ensured Firewall is allowing UDP packets
(2)  I have made the same IP address,subnet,gateway settings configurations.**

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say exactly what goes wrong based on this information.
I'd suggest trying Wireshark from https://www.wireshark.org/.

With that running on your windows PC, you can see if your packets are being sent out or not, and you can also see if the device responds or not. That way you can determine if the problem is in sending or receiving the packets.